# Getting Error: Unknown command: trade/test while running console command Yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am running below command and getting following error -

$php yii trade/test

Unknown command: trade/test

Did you mean "trade/test"?

Comment: you have a trade controller in /console/controllers folder ?

Comment: No. I am using module structure. trade is the module and i have TestController in console\modules\trade\controllers

Comment: Found the issue... I had defined incorrect function in controller. Now its working.